# It is possible to change the Icon of the status bar (notification icon) dynamically?

Tags: android, notifications, statusbar

I have an android APP, with a lot of activities.

In the login activiti of my app, i start a notification icon in the status bar, and it is fixed there until my app stops. Ok, it works.

But now i need one more thing, i need to changue the icon dynamically, programatically, with a service of my app. How can i do it?

How can i access to the notification icon of my app and then change the icon?

I would appreciate code examples to illustrate how to achieve this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just call `notify()` again on `NotificationManager` with a new `Notification` but the same unique ID as you used for the first one. It will replace your icon of the existing `Notification` (or display the new `Notification` if the user cleared the first one).

Comment: it doesn't works, im doing it but notification bar doesn't updates, it still shows the same text and icon :S

Comment: @AndroidUser99: OK, then cancel() the original Notification and raise the new one.

Comment: how can i cancel the original notification on that service?

Comment: @AndroidUser99: Call `cancel()` on `NotificationManager`, passing in the unique ID of the notification to remove.

Comment: but i have another problem now... it only shows the new tickerText ONE TIME, then, never shows it again. ¿why?

Comment: the tickerText is the text that appears for two or three seconds in the right of the icon in the status bar

Comment: @AndroidUser99: If you `notify()` an already existing `Notification`, it will no re-display the ticker text. If you need the ticker text to show, you need to `cancel()` the `Notification`, then `notify()` it again.

Answer (score 8):

You could use the iconLevel on the Notification:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#More

Create a xml file in res/drawable/myicon.xml with different level (different icon)
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LevelListDrawable.html

```
<level-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:maxLevel="0" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_wifi_signal_1" />
  <item android:maxLevel="1" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_wifi_signal_2" />
  <item android:maxLevel="2" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_wifi_signal_3" />
</level-list>
```

and set or (update) the level with:

```
Notification mNotification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
mNotification.iconLevel = 1;
mNoticationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mNotification);
```

Comment: This is really a more complete, and arguably "more correct", answer than the accepted one, and what I used and verified to work.